# New apple subscription items are not displaying in my unity application

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, subscribe

I'm managing my app's subscription products through Firebase. While I can display my existing products in the app, I'm facing an issue where newly created products are not showing up. I've consistently followed the same steps when creating new products. Has anything changed on Apple's side recently that could be causing this? Or are there any suggestions on how to troubleshoot and solve this issue?

Recently, I made changes to some items in Firebase for my app's subscription products. Strangely, the previously existing items are functioning as expected, but the newly added ones are not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're requesting the products specifically? Because you can't just create a product in the store dashboard and expect to get it automatically. You should fetch the product(s) specifically from Unity API(I assume you're using Unity's IAP SDK).